# Jenkins Pipeline SCM Push Config

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-multibranch

I have a Jenkins Pipeline configuration using a Jenkinsfile. I want to leverage Github web hooks, but the only option appears to be periodically polling Github in the "Scan Repository Triggers" section.

[image]

The help text says "*Push notification may be configured as per the SCM plugin used for each respective branch source*", however the SCM plugin does not have a webhook configuration option. Github web hooks work correctly on my non-pipeline projects.

How do I get Github web hooks to work on pipeline projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/224543927-GitHub-webhook-configuration? This article covers  GitHub webhook setup in Jenkins.